# Linq : How to search with 'Any' or 'All'

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, linq

I have a search page where you can enter 4 search criteria. User can enter all 4 or less and when I do the search I have to look for all 4 if they are entered and if not take all for the value not entered. Example: my search parameters are FirstName, LastName, City and Zip. Now if someone enters John and Zip 01803 I need to ignore other 2 and look for all Johns in that zip  code. Can I do that in one query somehow? I know I can do that if I write multiple ones to check which values are null but that looks not so tedious. I want to know if I can use 'Any' or 'All' in LINQ to do that?

```
 if (fname == null) fname = "";
 if (lname == null) lname = "";
 if (city == null) city = "";
 var results = from c in context.Company.Where(d => d.CompanyCode == identifikator)
                      join p in context.Person.Where(d => (d.FirstName.Any(??) || d.FirstName.Contains(fname)) && d.LastName.Contains(lname) && d.City.Contains(city) && d.ZIP==zip) on c.CompanyId equals p.Identifikation
                      join ts in context.TSSession on p.PersonId equals ts.PersonId

                      select new
                      {
                          firstname = p.FirstName,
                          lastname = p.LastName,
                          mail = p.EMail,
                          order = tp.Order,
                          timestamp = ts.TimeStamp,
                          personid = p.PersonId
                      };
```

Comment: Any() returns true or false depending if there is 0 or more items in the collection and All() if all items satisfy a condition.

Answer (score 2):

You can build your `where` expression like this:

```
var personsSubQuery = context.Persons;
if(fname != null)
     personsSubQuery = personsSubQuery.Where(x=>x.FirstName.Contains(fname));
if(lname != null)
     personsSubQuery = personsSubQuery.Where(x=>x.LastName.Contains(lname));
```

and so on.

then in your query just use `personsSubQuery` in place of your `context.Persons.Where`.

I don't see `Any` or `All` methods to be usable in this scenario.

Comment: Interesting. Do the queries get concatenated?

Comment: Linq to anything (and here is orm I suppose) works in stages first you prepare your linq query and when you iterate it is translated into sql query. So yes, it will be converted to single sql statement.

Comment: Thanks! I tried the way you suggested but get an error that Source type System.LINQ,IQueryable cannot be converted to target System.Data.Entity.Dbset. But this gave me an idea of sub query so what I tried is write a basic query like I have above 'results' and then do the sub query like  if (fname != null)
                reults = results.Where(x => x.firstname.Contains(fname));